# push array in const inside .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying  to push a value inside a const but its in a `.then` and it's not working do you know how can I do that ?

I get a value in my `console.log(newResult)` in my `if` but the data is not pushed in my const `newResult` in the return

`res.status(200).json(newResult);`

```
.then(function (friends) {
    if (friends) {
        const newResult = [];
        friends.forEach((r) => {
            if (r.UserID == userFound.id) {
                models.User.findOne({
                        where: {
                            id: r.idFriend
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function(userFound) {
                        newResult.push({
                            id: r.id,
                            user: {
                                id: r.User.id,
                                email: userFound.email,
                                username: userFound.username
                            }

                        });
                        console.log(newResult)
                    })
            } else
                newResult.push({
                    id: r.id,
                    user: {
                        id: r.User.id,
                        email: r.User.email,
                        username: r.User.username
                    }
                });
            console.log(newResult)
        });
        res.status(200).json(newResult);
    }
}
```

every test realised return an empty tab when i go in my if condition

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never work because, you are doing `async` calls 
`models.User.findOne` inside forEach.

You'll get results on `console.log` when async call to database for fetching user is complete.

But before this all happens the `forEach` is done executing and code hits the line `res.status(200).json(newResult);` and you see no results from your `if` condition.

Instead of using this approach go for mongoose `populate` and populate userObject based `userID` while finding `friends` this way you won't have to do async call inside the `forEach`.

> Read about mongoose populate at:  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html